# when computing $\;\lim_{x\to a, y\to b} f(x,y) $, why is it there are infinite directions of letting (x,y) approach (a,b)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose we are trying to compute $$\;\lim_{x\to a, y\to b} f(x,y) $$

My textbook claims

> For functions of a single variable, when we let x approach a, there
>   are only two possible directions of approach, from the left or from
>   the right...For functions of two variables the situation is not as
>   simple because we can let (x,y) approach (a,b) from an infinite number
>   of directions in any manner whatsoever (see figure below) as long as
>   (x,y) stays within the domain of f.

[image]

My question: why infinite? If I remember calculus 1 correctly, when taking limits of a single variable $$\;\lim_{x\to a} f(x) $$ you approach $a$ when $x < a$ and see where it takes you.  Then you approach $a$ when $x > a$. That adds to two ways of getting to $a$. In the multivariable case you do the exact same thing with an additional two steps: approach $b$ when $y<b$ and approach $b$ when $y>b$. That's a total of 4 ways to approach $(a,b)$ So how are we getting to infinite ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When talking about limits in a multivariate environment forget about "directions" when approaching a point ${\bf p}=(a,b)$. Note that some advocatus diaboli could even force you to approach ${\bf p}$ along some spiral! Therefore the "infinity" you have to face when working with this path concept for limits is much larger than you thought.

Note that **limits are defined in terms of distances, $\epsilon$, and** $\delta$. The fact
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} f(x,y)=z$$
holds if for any given $\epsilon>0$ you can find a $\delta>0$ such that
$$0<\|(x,y)-(a,b)\|<\delta\quad\Rightarrow\quad |f(x,y)-z|<\epsilon\ .$$
Here the distance $\|(x,y)-(a,b)\|$ could be euclidean distance $\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}$, but one of
$$|x-a|+|y-b],\qquad \max\{|x-a|, |y-b|\}$$
would serve as well. The former of these two is called $l^1$ distance, the latter $l^\infty$ distance.

By the way: You wrote $\lim_{x\to a, \ y\to b} f(x,y)$. The limit described in the above has to be distinguished from the "iterated limit" $\lim_{x\to a}\>\lim_{y\to b} f(x,y)$.

Answer (score 4):

For instance, you can approach $(a,b)$ along a straight line of any slope, which is already an infinite number of ways.

Comment: approaching $(a,b)$ along a straight line of any slope should also apply to a function of single variable too, as $x\to a$, right? Why doesn't the straight line of any slope offer infinite number of ways to $x\to a$ for a function with one variable?

Comment: Since in the single variable case, your entire domain is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but in the 2 variable case, your domain is a subset of the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be a point in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, and let 
$S$ be the set of points $q \in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $|p-q|=r, r > 0$. Since $S$ contains infinitely many points and for any $q\in S$ we have a unique "straight" path $f(t)=tp+(1-t)q,$ $0 \leq t \leq 1,$ from $q$ to $p$, we say that there are infinitely many ways to approach $p$ in the plane.

So when evaluating limits in the two dimensional case, you can save yourself time by composing whatever function you are inspecting with the function $f$ given above, and see if any specific q gives you any problems.

Comment: @Cory - if you draw out all the infinite straight line segments $f(t$) then you get a sphere with radius $r$, right? But we can do almost the exact same thing with the 1-dimensioal case, except instead of infinite "straight" lines forming a sphere, you get infinite "straight" lines forming a circle. So I'm still confused why there aren't infinite ways to approach a point in the simple 1 dimensional case of $f(x)= x^2 $ and approaching the point $(2,4)$

Comment: There all more than two ways to approach a point p on the real number line if you account for the velocity you travel at it but your book is talking about direction from which the point is approached. To go back to the example I gave, think of what the analogue of S would be in $\mathbb{R}$. Fix a point p on the real number line some $r>0$ and convince yourself there are not more than two point Whose distance from p is equal to r.